# Пересчёт рейтинга удалённых вопросов

Tags: дефект, голосование

1. Нашёл удалённый вопрос с рейтингом -10.
2. Открыл его, увидел рейтинг -10.
3. Посмотрел комментарии.
4. Нажал на рейтинг, чтобы посмотреть плюсы и минусы и увидел +0 -9 (что в сумме не -10).
5. С тех пор даже при обновлении страницы показывается рейтинг -9.

Что произошло?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710699/178988

[image: скриншот]

Кстати, про -10 там даже комментарий есть.

[image: скриншот комментария]

Comment: Учётку одного из голосующих удалили? Вообще, наверное, не имеет смысла в реальном времени пересчитывать рейтинг удаленных вопросов, потому что они не учитываются в рейтинге пользователя. Микрооптимизация?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а по-моему не имеет смысла при запросе количества пересчитывать.

Comment: Имеете право на такое мнение.

Comment: Видимо, от 1 до 10 не включительно